# PowerShell - Invoke Command on Remote Machines/Computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

There's plenty of forums/material regarding the subject line, but cannot seem to get an answer for my problem.

I'm trying to execute a script from the main server (SRV01) that will clean the temp folders on the secondary servers (SRV02, SRV03).

Here is the script:

```
#Set the machines on the network to run the script on
$VDST = @("SRV02", "SRV03")

#Folder locations to clean out
$TempFolder = @("C:\Windows\Temp\*", "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\temp\*")

#This function actually performs the clean up operation
Function executeCleanUp
    {
        $TempFolder = $args[0]
        $machineNames = $args[2]

        ForEach($machine in $machineNames){

            Get-PSSession -ComputerName $machine | Format-Table -Property ComputerName, InstanceID

            Write-Host 'Starting Clean Up...'

            #Loop through the sub folders in the registry location
            ForEach($folderLocation in $TempFolder)
            {
                $StrInput = 'Remove-Item -Path ' + $folderLocation + ' -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'

                $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument $StrInput 

                Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -TaskName "CleanUp"

                Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "CleanUp"

                Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "CleanUp" -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

            }
    }

#Execute Script on specified machines - provided in array above
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VDST -ScriptBlock ${function:executeCleanUp} -ArgumentList $TempFolder, $VDST
```

After running the above, I get the error:

> A specified logon session does not exist

So, I came across a forum where it was suggested to do the following:

```
#Remote Server (VDI)
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server

#Expected Output
#This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.

#Local Machine
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegatedCredentials 'SRV01'

#Expected Output
#The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/SRV01.

#Local Machine
#Open gpedit.msc 
#Browse to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation. 
#Double-click "Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication"
#Enable the setting 
#Add the build server to the server list as WSMAN/BuildServerName.

#Example Execution:
#Invoke-Command -ComputerName <REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME> -Authentication CredSSP -Credential <USERNAME> -ScriptBlock { #code}
```

I've done all this, but now I get the error:

> A computer policy does not allow the delegation of the user
>   credentials to the target computer

Also, I am assuming the line

> WSMAN/BuildServerName

should be written

> WSMAN/SRV02

Answer (score 0):

The 2 hop authentication issue came up because you are trying to list remote sessions with in your remote session
`Get-PSSession -ComputerName $machine | Format-Table -Property ComputerName, InstanceID`

If you just want to clear some files on the remote servers the code below should work with no need for CredSPP.

Setting `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will make trouble shooting difficult, It's easier to check if the file exists before you try to delete it.

```
$TempFolder = $args[0]
$ComputerArray = "SRV02","SRV03"
$ScriptBlock =
{

    foreach ($Folder in $TempFolders)
    {
        if (Test-Path -Path $TempFolder)
        {
            Remove-Item -Path $Folder -force
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerArray -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $TempFolder
```

Wrong answer:

Your issue is two hop authentication.
You can't nest remote sessions with default windows settings.
While this would not be considered to be best practice, you can enable CredSSP to bypass the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-security-support-provider

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp?view=powershell-7

Could you either log on to SVR01 to run the script or run the script against the target machines from your own computer?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes I believe it is two hop authentication. The article I read was on how to enable the CredSSP "setup" but it just doesn't allow me to get the task done. I am currently logged into the SRV01 and trying to run it from there.

Comment: I'm wondering if the part where I need to put in the `WSMAN/BuildServerName` is the problem. I am assuming it should be `WSMAN/SRV02`

Comment: Sorry, it has been a long time since I did this as it is something I avoid due to security restrictions in my environment. You need to add a registry entry. `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly` this should be a DWORD with a value of 1

Comment: Thank you again for the response Dave. I have created the reg entry, but could you perhaps explain a little more on how to "use" it now please?

Comment: I have reread your question and I think we are fixing a non existing problem. TASK: You want to delete temp files from SVR02 and SVR03 from SVR01, Correct? QUESTION: Why are you using a scheduled task? Do you want this task to be run at a regular interval?

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember EXACTLY why I ended up going the scheduled task route, but I believe it was because I don't want to **have** go onto the machine (SRV02 and SRV03) to "execute" some command. I want to be able to do it all remotely. I believe "kicking off" a scheduled task from PS bypassed the authentication issue.. It worked like a couple of times if I remember, but then I noticed it wasn't cleaning the folders. But yes, your question is 100% correct.